# Enhance dates display in education section for non-ranges

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Rendering of dates in the "Education" section is currently a bit weird, if only one date of the range is given.

e.g. entering:

```
BSc. Computer Science|Foo university       - 2014
Math|Bar university                   2014 -
```

would render like this:

```
BSc. Computer Science|Foo university      2014
Math|Bar university                       2014
```

**Possible solution:**

In the "Experience" section it is possible to display a "Current" for the current employer. This would be useful for Education too mark it as "Ongoing" or "...".